# synchronous web service asp.net responce and request in XSD format

Tags: asp.net, web-services, xsd

my client has provided me 2 XSD files one is for request and another is for responce and in sample WSDl he has provided ,import namespaces like ,

```
     <xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://xsd.ge.com/testService/Rq" schemaLocation="testRq.xsd"/><xsd:import namespace="http://xsd.ge.com/testService/Rs" schemaLocation="testRs.xsd"/>
  </xsd:schema>
```

my client wants responce and requests in xsd format using synchronous web service, i am new to web service. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can Generate XSD from Response XML.

Refer to This: [XML Schema Definition Tool (Xsd.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)